# Bootstrap first line code not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: This is my output]

I do not know what I have done wrong. Everything is perfect. Here is the code. I am using Django framework and google chrome as the browser. I feel that something is missing in my PC. I do not know what it is. Because the code the perfect. Why am I not getting the navbar perfectly?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{% static 'main/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    </div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'main/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image of your page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq4m1.png)

Replacing your Django links to bootstrap css and js with `http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js` respectively, your menu does indeed display correctly.

Something probably went wrong with your Django links. I'd check all these imports. For one, you've imported bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js twice: in the head and in the body.

Comment: Please see the code I have updated it. And my django links are working just fine I have tested them by viewing the source in chrome and going to each link. All the CSS and JS files are opening. No error in that. Thank You :)

Comment: That's strange because your page is showing just fine in my Chrome browser when I simply replace your bootstrap links. Have you tried doing that, just to check?

Comment: Thanks. They are working now. I wonder what was the problem. I included all the files :|

Comment: Everything suddenly started working without having changed anything? :/

Comment: No No, I did what you told me to. I replaced my links with the ones you gave me.

Comment: The differance between my bootstrap.min.css and the one which is CDN is, mine starts with, ``/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 (ht..`` while the one in your given link starts with, ``/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (htt..`` .Any idea why this error was happening?

Comment: I don't know Bootstrap 4 so maybe they totally changed everything and your code is meaningless for that version, I don't know, that seems far fetched... Good that it works now in any case. Please don't forget to validate my answer as it solved your issue :-)

Comment: sure :) I will.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you imported 2 different versions of jQuery , `3.1.1` in `<head>` and `1.12` at the bottom of `<body>`. You also did that for `bootstrap.min.js`.

Delete the `jQuery` in `<head>` and `bootstrap.min.js`, and put them right before the `</body>` tag, like this:

```
<!-- jQuery 3.2.1 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then, try again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Look at the official documentation from Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default, and **DON'T** switch the ``<nav>`` with ``contair-fluid`` class, that's not a correct way to do it! Please look at the sample from the official Bootstrap documentation on the link I gave you

Answer (score 0):

Twice connected scripts

In the head section jquery.min.... and bootstrap.min....

And before /body

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `container-fluid` before the `nav` so it will fill the screen and will also cover the `navbar`.

Comment: I used ``<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">`` and it still doesn't work for me. Same result.

Comment: He doesn't need to do that, look at the code http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default ``container-fluid`` class is after the ``<nav>`` tag.

Comment: i tried and got success by removing your css and js links for bootstrap and putting the below links you can try these and see the result 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please see the updated code. I have done what people have asked me to. I have removed the JS from header and moved it below body. I am still getting the same result